# What does the 'action' part of a form tag mean in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, action

When I have the following `action` in a form tag, what does the '/Account/Profile` part mean?

```
<form method="post" action="/Account/Profile"
```

Is it a Filename for a view? Is it an action?

Comment: The term "action" in this case is actually coming from the HTML spec, not MVC. It is the URL that the form will be sent (posted) to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on the routing you have setup but if you stick to the conventions `Account` is a controller (a file called AccountController.cs) and `Profile` is an action method of this controller:

```
// Account is a controller
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    // Profile is an action method
    public ActionResult Profile()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I would recommend you following some of the [tutorials here](http://www.asp.net/mvc) to get yourself familiarized with the basics of ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the default route Account is the controller and Profile is the action. The controller is the class and action is the method that will be called. You can check out your routes in Global.asax file

Answer (score 0):

As was nicely explained by Darin, it all depends upon the `Routing` configuration.

for example, if this is your `routing-configuration` for the `Account` controller is something like below,

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "AccountRouting",
                routeTemplate: "Account/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

and when you put something like,

```
 <form method="post" action="/account/Profile" > .... </form>
```

will take the user (upon form submission) to the `Profile` action-method of the `account` controller.

If your `routing-configuration` for the `Account` controller is something like below,

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "AccountRouting",
                routeTemplate: "cntrl/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

and the form tag is like,

```
<form method="post" action="/cntrl/Profile" > .... </form>
```

this will take you to the `Profile` method of the `account` controller.

so, the point is `"this depends upon your routing configuration!"`